# Feasibility of using Laravel compared to Codeigniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I have been developing in Codeigniter for awhile now. I have recently read that Laravel is currently the most modern and best framework. I am interested in learning it for my next project. I'm hoping that someone could help to answer some questions that I have about Laravel.

1) How would I host it? Laravel seems to rely on composer a lot and that requires a terminal. For CI, I just download a folder and load it up to my Webserver and I can run it.

2) Dev environment. I have been using Netbeans that is connected to my server and it can push updates instantly. I want to connect it to git soon for some versioning as well. Is it the same for Laravel? How would I update it?

Comment: Very Broad Question, could be closed

Comment: Sorry, someone edited my questions. I have reduced it to be more focused. Hope thats alright.

Comment: You have to install the dependency into your server to make laravel work in server. Otherwise it wont work in server. 2. Its like same. You can use it. If you use SSH then it will more easier for you to create codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here, I have been developing Applications in Codeigniter 2,3 for past 5 years and now I am learning Laravel and have starting making beginners level application in Laravel Here are my findings which might help you

**Difficulties**

- For Codeigniter Developer, Instantly playing everything by using router is kind of difficult. Although router is used in codeigniter as well
- Installing and setting up Laravel seems like a tricky and very lengthy job especially the use of composer which is an extra thing as compared to codeigniter which is just download and uncompress or copy paste installation procedure.

**But Why Laravel?**

Object Relation Modeling - Eloquent ORM

We can easily create relations and joins with query builder or active records in codeigniter but to enforce referential integrity in database, we have to write triggers in our database or define relations. Luckily in Laravel the relations are made with one line of code and does a lot of job. Whereas in Codeigniter that's a lot of manual code writing.

Integration of off the self Packages.

There are thousands of developed packages readily available on packagist, which is a repository composer uses to download software packages. You just have to write one or two lines of code at composer terminal and it does all the rest, create models, controllers, views. All you have to do is include them or change the styling as per your layouts.

Think of Laravel as a PHP framework for extremely lazy developers who want to write very less and re-usable code and do lot of work from it.

**Learning Resources**
[Laravel 5.2 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) that's the one I started with, excellent course and [Modern Web Development with Laravel](https://www.udemy.com/modern-web-development-with-laravel/learn/v4/overview)

**Uploading on Shared hosting**

[Click here](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.8gnt7d8vp) for tutorial

Comment: Thank you for answering! How do you host your Laravel site? Can it be uploaded like CI and just run or do I have to do anything to the server? The reason I ask is because I found some guides to loading it on shared hosting and it seemed like quite a process.

Comment: i edited my answer, see another link for shared hosting , that will help